# How to make root json on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm sorry I'm not good in English.

I am trying to find topic as same my problem.My problem is json not root.

This is my json data:

```
[
{
created_at: "2013-07-26T02:49:55Z",
description: "hgfhgfhf",
iconapp: null,
id: 13,
name: "test1",
updated_at: "2013-07-26T02:49:55Z",
},
{
created_at: "2013-07-26T02:54:40Z",
description: "sadsadas",
iconapp: null,
id: 14,
name: "asdadas",
updated_at: "2013-07-26T02:54:40Z",
}
]
```

but I want to my json data have root element like this:

```
- Apps: [
{
created_at: "2013-07-26T02:49:55Z",
description: "hgfhgfhf",
iconapp: null,
id: 13,
name: "test1",
updated_at: "2013-07-26T02:49:55Z",
},
{
created_at: "2013-07-26T02:54:40Z",
description: "sadsadas",
iconapp: null,
id: 14,
name: "asdadas",
updated_at: "2013-07-26T02:54:40Z",
}
]
```

Json root is "Apps".How do I do ?

Help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a configuration thing. By default the root is not included in json. You can enable it via:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

If you want it application wide add it to a new initializer that will run the code when the app is started. Its documented here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json